# Ruby: Check if a string contains multiple values

Tags: ruby

I want to see if any arbitrary characters `c1,c2,c3...` turn up in a given string.

I'm looking for a nice way to rework the following example:

```
val = String.new("abc123")
if val.include? "a" or val.include? "2" or val.include? "3"
  ...
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write as below :

```
val = "abc123"
val[/[1af]/] # => "a"
val[/[w6f]/] # => nil
```

So change your code as

```
if val[/[a23]/]
  #...
end
```

See the documentation of [`str[regexp] → new_str or nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

> If a **Regexp** is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
arr = [ 'a', '2', '3' ]

s = "abc123"

arr.any? { |letter| s.include? letter } # Will return true if any element is present
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression.

```
string_to_check = "hello random abc123"

string_to_check =~ /[a23]/
```

That would return the position where the first match is. Then if you would want to know if it is true or false you could just do `== 0` or `!= 0`

```
(string_to_check =~ /[a23]/) != 0
```

Comment: No. What happens when the regex is not found? It returns `nil`. You don't want that. So `string_to_check =~ /[rrr]/` returns `nil`, and `nil != 0` returns `true`. Easiest solution: `!!(string_to_check =~ /[a23]/)`